# Is it possible to upload a file to django before submitting a form?

Tags: python, django, forms, file, upload

I'm working on a webapp that lets users upload rather large video files and (based on data in a form they fill out) process them. At the moment it's setup to start uploading the file as soon as the form is submitted (as that's how django does it) but I'd like to take advantage of the time in which the user is busy filling out that form (assuming they start uploading the file first).

Is this possible? how would I go about achieving this? Is this a django feature?

The way I've got it now is that I have this model for my video:

```
class Video(models.Model):
    def user_directory_path_thumbnail(instance, filename):
        # file will be uploaded to MEDIA_ROOT/thumbnails/<identifier>.png
        return 'thumbnails/{0}.png'.format(instance.identifier)

    def user_directory_path_video(instance, filename):
        # file will be uploaded to MEDIA_ROOT/videos/<identifier>.png
        return 'videos/{0}.mp4'.format(instance.identifier)

    uploader    = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title       = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    identifier  = models.SlugField(blank=True, null=True)
    category    = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    description_short = models.CharField(max_length=300, default="none")
    description = models.TextField(default="none")
    uploaded    = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated     = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    time        = models.IntegerField()
    thumbnail   = ResizedImageField(size=[320, 180],upload_to=user_directory_path_thumbnail, force_format='PNG')
    type        = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    media       = models.FileField(upload_to=user_directory_path_video, default=settings.MEDIA_ROOT + '/videos/test.mp4')


    # Used to show video title in django admin page instead of 'video object(n)'
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "/view/" + self.identifier
```

and my form for the uploading:

```
class VideoUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    iquery_choices = Category.objects.values_list('description', flat=True)
    category = forms.ChoiceField(choices = iquery_choices)
    videoFile = forms.FileField()
    class Meta:
        model = Video
        fields = [
            'title',
            'description',
            'description_short',
            'time',
            'thumbnail',
            'type',
            'media',
        ]

    def clean_thumbnail(self):
        picture = self.cleaned_data.get("thumbnail")
        if not picture:
            raise forms.ValidationError("No Image")
        else:
            w, h = get_image_dimensions(picture)
            if w/h != (16/9):
                raise forms.ValidationError("Image in wrong aspect ratio (should be 16:9)")
        return picture
```

Do I need a separate model and form for the files or can you leave them in the same model?

Comment: It's not a limitation of Django, but this is how HTTP actually works. As a workaround, you can create a separate form specifically for files. So when the user chooses a file, you can automatically submit that form using JavaScript so that the file starts uploading in the background and meanwhile the user can fill out the *other* form. But, it's too much of a headache, really, and in my opinion, not worth it.

Comment: Allright i'll check it out